# Joining Together Strings and variables

Tags: concatenation

I am trying to join together strings and variables as part of formatting the output of my code. For example how do I print the line "5 trees" where the number 5 is a variable n that could be changing. I've tried the following, which doesn't work:

```
 n=5;
 Print[n <> "trees"]
```

Any idea on how to get that to print as "5 trees"? Thanks!

Comment: `Print[n, " trees"]` and take a look `StringForm` or `Templates` friends.

Answer (score 9):

For trivial combinations, simple `Print` combinations work well.

For more complex operations, take a look at `StringForm`:

```
var1 = "Tree";
var2 = 10;

StringForm["The `1` is about `2` feet tall...", var1, var2]

(* "The Tree is about 10 feet tall..." *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 5;
Print[ToString[n] <> " trees"]
```