# Outputting a concatenation of a string and a variable within a loop

Tags: output-formatting, output

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78907/joining-together-strings-and-variables) question, it was mentioned that one can output the concatenation of a string and a variable by using `StringForm[]`:

```
var1 = "Tree";
var2 = 10;

StringForm["The `1` is about `2` feet tall...", var1, var2]

(* "The Tree is about 10 feet tall..." *)
```

This works. However, when I try to use it within a loop, I get no output whatsoever:

```
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
(
   var1 = "Tree";
   var2 = 10;

   StringForm["The `1` is about `2` feet tall...", var1, var2]
)]
```

I don't understand why there is no output here as I am just repeating the same operation $i$ times. What am I missing?

---

EDIT: The aim is to perform a task within the `For` loop, and print some intermediary results every $n$ iterations.

Comment: Use `Table`. `For` does not return anything.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you for your comment. What about the case where a bunch of operations are being executed within the For loop, and some intermediary results must be printed out every $n$ iterations?

Comment: Only printed or collected? Use `Print` or for the latter case `Sow/Reap`. At the end you can have `Table` to manage your loop and `Table[proc; string, {i, 10}]` or something. Assuming string generation is the last step only.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use `Table`. In the meantime, can you please explain why a perfectly valid output does *not* output when placed within a `For` loop? As a software developer, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: `For` evaluates expression in a loop but does not return anything. Here's more about that: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124077/5478

Comment: Thank you. I will read that

Comment: @Flermat this questions was closed as [duplicate](https://wolfr.am/wbjeaXyW) and now it has been flagged for [reopening](https://wolfr.am/yEIBr9In). Does the question linked as duplicate answer your question or not? If it doesn't, [edit] your question and explain why so we can reopen it and get the answer you need.

Comment: @rhermans Yes it answers my question, thank you. You can close this question.